# SoundCloud widget events not firing

Tags: javascript, api, widget, soundcloud

I'm having problems with the SoundCloud Widget API.

For some reason the PLAY and PLAY_PROGRESS events are not firing after playing the track using the auto_play option. The READY event is working fine, though.

Here's the code:

```
player = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud-player'));

player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, this.SC_onPlayerReady.bind(this));
player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY, this.SC_onPlayerPlay.bind(this));
player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.PLAY_PROGRESS, this.SC_onPlayProgress.bind(this));
```

Help from SC staff appreciated, as I can't find any solution to it :- )

Thanks,
Pierre

Comment: Hey Pierre! Any particular browser? Do you have a link?

Comment: Hey Misha, I'm using Chrome (v23). The same problem occurs for Safari (no surprise). As for Firefox the widget is not loading at all. No, sorry, I've got no link as it's still work in progress. :-/ The playground works fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting this.

Indeed, `SC.Widget.Events.Play` is not firing right now when `auto_play` parameter is set to `true`. The fix is on its way to be deployed.

However, `PLAY_PROGRESS` event is fine, as you can see in the following example: http://jsbin.com/adubav/6/edit

Comment: No worries. Your example is working for me too, even the PLAY event if I programmatically play it. On my local version the PLAY is not even triggered when I do the exact same thing, nor is the PLAY_PROGRESS. Can't find any difference between our code.

Comment: If I move the binding of the PLAY and PLAY_PROGRESS events to the callback function of the READY event, I'm getting errors about being unable to use cross-domain postMessage.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you'd upload the code you have, I'd be glad to look at it.

Comment: This contains the relevant parts of the code I'm working on (can't disclose the whole thing):
http://jsbin.com/adubav/12/edit.

The example works fine for me

Comment: Do you still have trouble with widget?

Comment: Yea, I still have. It's a mystery to me.